# Preloader keep loading after loading image php

Tags: php, html, qr-code

I am trying to implement a download button for each QR image in my page. It works fine exept when I click on the button and download the image, the preloader keeps loading. If I remove the preloader it works perfectly. What is the problem?
Here is my code:

Main page code

```
 <div class="preloader">
   <div class="preloader-body">
     <div class="cssload-container">
        <img src="images/AC_logo_ico.png" class="img-fluid">
        <div class="cssload-speeding-wheel"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="page"> 
   <div class="card product tumbnail">
    <img class="img-fluid" id="QR_'.$row["ID_table"].'" src="'.$row["QR"].'" />
    <a id="download" href="download_qr_code.php?url='.encodeURIComponent($row["QR"]).'">
      <i title="Download"  class="fa fa-download fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
   </div>
 </div>

  function encodeURIComponent($str){
    $revert = array('%21'=>'!', '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')');
    return strtr(rawurlencode($str), $revert);
  }
```

Download page code

```
<?php
  $url = $_GET['url'];
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header("Content-type: image/png");
  header('Expires: 0');
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= qrcode_".time().".png");
  readfile($url);
?>
```

Preloader code

```
$window.on( 'load', function () {
   if (plugins.preloader.length && !isNoviBuilder) {
     pageTransition({
        target: document.querySelector( '.page' ),
        delay: 0,
        duration: 500,
        classIn: 'fadeIn',
        classOut: 'fadeOut',
        classActive: 'animated',
        conditions: function (event, link) {
          return link && !/(\#|javascript:void\(0\)|callto:|tel:|mailto:|:\/\/)/.test(link) && !event.currentTarget.hasAttribute('data-lightgallery');
        },
        onTransitionStart: function ( options ) {
          setTimeout( function () {
            plugins.preloader.removeClass('loaded');
          }, options.duration * .75 );
        },
        onReady: function () {
          plugins.preloader.addClass('loaded');
          windowReady = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Since it's a regular download as an attachment, there's nothing to tell the initiating page when it's completed. That's just how it is.

Comment: What "preloader" are you talking about?

Comment: Assuming these are images hosted under the same origin, this doesn't need an extra PHP script, you can achieve this with the `download` attribute on a direct link to the image URL. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Comment: @CBroe I'm talking about the page preloader (that is not in the 
attached code). I've tryied to do with `download` but it doesn't work. I thought it's a problem with the content-type/content-disposition in the download page but honestly I can't tell

Comment: So you are not showing us how your preloader works (which makes it pretty impossible for us to tell why it might be behaving differently than intended in this situation), and for the alternative I suggested, you only give a "didn't work" response, again without showing us what you actually did (so impossible for us to tell if you might have done something wrong.) If you _want_ our help, you need to make it _possible_ first of all.

Comment: @CBroe I've edited my question with the preloader code, hoping it will help. The download attribute problem is that it downloads the entire main page and save it as a png. In that case the preloader keeps loading too.

Comment: That looks like it does more than just provide a "preloader" - actually applying some sort of page transition appears to be the primary purpose here. Via the `conditions` option, it appears to provide a way to exclude certain links from getting the behavior  applied (and with that, presumably the preloader functionality as well), making exceptions for certain `href` patterns. And the last part appears to check for certain custom data attribute not to be set - so you should probably try and exclude those links using something similar.

Comment: _"The download attribute problem is that it downloads the entire main page"_ - what did you set the `href` to? (Which brings us, again, to the point of _show what you tried_, instead of giving vague & imprecise verbal descriptions only!) That must the URL of the image in this case.

Comment: I've tryied to do something like this: `<img class="img-fluid" id="QR_'.$row["ID_table"].'" src="'.$row["QR"].'"  />` `<a id="download" href="#QR_'.$row["ID_table"].'" download="QR_'.$row["Code"].'.png">` where `$row["QR"]` is a Google chart url for QR codes